# jQuery mobile form is not allowing PHP outputs?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I used jQuery mobile to generate my forms and use it in my PHP application. However, it is not outputing my echo messages. When I checked the generated HTML, it shows the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
            </body>
</html>
Invalid question ID
```

I checked jQuery mobile documentation and they've asked me to do this: `data-ajax="false"` However, it is not working. What is the problem? Why it's not outputting my PHP messages?

UPDATE:

PHP code

```
$sql = "SELECT active FROM questions where question_id='$qid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$active = $row[0];
if ($active != 1) {
    die('Invalid question ID');
}
```

Comment: What is the PHP code that generates this page?

Comment: I've updated the question with PHP code.

Comment: Because `$active` is not `1`

Comment: If active is 0, it should output "invalid question id" but it's not outputting that.

Comment: @EISS do you have `form` on page or where is get variable `$qid` ?

Comment: From a parameter in the URL. Anyway, this was solved ages ago I just forgot to post back.